# Maven build failed for Carbon Api Management in WS02

Tags: api, wso2

Hi I am trying to customize wso2 and the **latest source code** giving me **duplicate class** error. The code generated is generating extra classes which is leading to compilation error. I want to build API Manager, in which the prerequisite is to build **carbon api management** which is what **failing** now. Please help.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
8.1:compile (default-compile) on project org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v
1: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/v1
/impl/ApisApiServiceImpl.java:[63,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.res
t.api.store.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/TagsApiServiceImpl.java:[20,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest
.api.store.v1.impl.TagsApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/ApiProductsApiServiceImpl.java:[28,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apim
gt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApiProductsApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/v1
/impl/SearchApiServiceImpl.java:[46,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.r
est.api.store.v1.impl.SearchApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl.java:[23,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.ap
imgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.SubscriptionsApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/SettingsApiServiceImpl.java:[21,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.
rest.api.store.v1.impl.SettingsApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:[30,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.api
mgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/ImportApiServiceImpl.java:[21,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.re
st.api.store.v1.impl.ImportApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/ExportApiServiceImpl.java:[20,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.re
st.api.store.v1.impl.ExportApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/v1
/impl/ThrottlingPoliciesApiServiceImpl.java:[30,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.car
bon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ThrottlingPoliciesApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/SelfSignupApiServiceImpl.java:[21,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimg
t.rest.api.store.v1.impl.SelfSignupApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/gen/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/imp
l/v1/TenantsApiServiceImpl.java:[19,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.r
est.api.store.v1.impl.TenantsApiServiceImpl
[ERROR] /D:/projects/wso2/carbon-apimgt-master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon
.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/rest/api/store/v1
/impl/SdkGenApiServiceImpl.java:[34,8] duplicate class: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.r
est.api.store.v1.impl.SdkGenApiServiceImpl
```

Comment: this could be a windows specific issue. is there a way for you to try on a different os?

Comment: I did tried in two different windows version machine.I even tried with different java version in 8. Same issue with other versions as well.

Comment: I have excluded that package from compiler plugin for now.